# Delete row from database with a button in table (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem, I have a table which shows data form a DB, in every row of this table (which is dynamically generated) I have a button for delete the row from the DB and so the row in my table will disappear. But I have no idea of how to catch the ID or the name of the value in the DB.

Here is my php code until now:

```
$del = new USER();

$stmt = $find->runQuery("SELECT  course_id , course_name , course_description , course_begin_date , course_price  FROM courses");
$stmt->execute();

if(isset($_POST['delete_course'])) 
{
$cid = strip_tags($_POST['txt_id']);

try 
{
    if ($del->deleteCourse($cid)) {
            $del->redirect('courses.php');
        }   
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
                    <th>Costo</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <?php 
                foreach($stmt->FetchAll() as $results) {                        
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<td name="txt_id">' . $results['course_id'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $results['course_name'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $results['course_description'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $results['course_begin_date'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $results['course_price'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td class="del">
                          <button type="submit" name="delete_course" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
                          </td>';
                    echo '</form>';
                    echo "</tr>";

                }
                ?>
            </table>
```

And my method of deleteCourse

```
public function deleteCourse($cid){

    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM courses WHERE course_id=:cid ");

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show us the new USER->deleteCourse($cid) method definition ?

Comment: Is at the end of the post, Is a class that i created but is too large for show, so I only posted the deleteCourse($cid) method

Comment: Deleting is irreversible without recourse to a backup. For this reason, it's more usual to have a column which acts as a visibility flag, and use an UPDATE to set that to 1 or 0, as appropriate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do this by two ways if you dont want use Ajax

**1.GET method**

**2.POST method**

you can do this with GET method by passing id in url example-

```
echo '<a href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourfile.php?uid='.$results['course_id'].'"></a>';
```

then you can get this value. example-

```
if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
$courseid = $_GET['uid'];
}
```

or you can do with POST method .then you need to create a form and send value in hidden field.
example -

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_course_id" value="<?php echo $results['course_id']; ?>">
 <button type="submit" name="delete_course" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
</form>
```

and you will get this id after form post like

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_course'])) 
{
$courseid = strip_tags($_POST['delete_course_id']);
}
```

Comment: GET do nothing, even if i do `if ($del->deleteCourse($uid)) {
            $del->redirect('courses.php');
        }  `

POST same thing, do nothing when i click the button

Comment: did you check $uid value in url .show me what url u got after submit.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I did't execute my sql query in the method, but i could do it without your POST way. Huge thanks

Comment: Where is the part where you are deleting the row?

Answer (score 1):

why are you using form? you can just use anchor tag and pass the id of the current row to it for example

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $results['id']; ?>"> Delete Row</a>
after this make delete.php file and check if id is set or not by using
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

//then delete the row which id is passed
//reload the page the record will be disappeared
//for reloading your page use this

header("Location:index.php");

}
```

Comment: I did this but it didn't work...

Answer (score -1):

```
    del = new USER();

    $stmt = $find->runQuery("SELECT  course_id , course_name , course_description , course_begin_date , course_price  FROM courses");
    $stmt->execute();

    if(isset($_GET['delete_course'])) 
    {


    try 
    {
        if ($del->deleteCourse($_GET['delete_course'])) {
                $del->redirect('courses.php');
            }   
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
?>

    <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
                        <th>Costo</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php 
                    foreach($stmt->FetchAll() as $results) { ?>                       
                       <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $results['course_id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $results['course_name']; ?> </td>
                       <td><?php echo $results['course_description']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $results['course_begin_date'] ; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $results['course_price'] ; ?></td>
                        <td class="del">
                              <button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" onclick="window.location.href = 'filename.php?delete_course=<?php echo $results['course_id']; ?>'" >Borrar</button>
                              </td>

                       </tr>
                <?php
}
                ?>
            </table>

<?php 
    public function deleteCourse($cid){

        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM courses WHERE course_id=$cid ");

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


Try like this. Let me know is it working or not.
```

Comment: Did not work, php ask me for a ; even when i concatenate corrctly

Comment: I think it works, but get unexpected token } , so it does nothing

Comment: Check all braces are closed properly.